# Cache on Chromebook

Tags: google-chrome, caching

I'm doing a report for a course on the differences between the hardware specs on different laptop devices. We're asked to be specific, so I'm comparing the "shared L3 cache" of a Macbook Air to the "1MB of CPU cache" on a Chromebook. I'm having difficulty locating exactly what type of cache the chromebook is running. I've not had any luck finding anything more specific then that. L1, l2 and L3 just don't come up under anything I've researched. Is this because the Chromebook does not use that type, or is it only L1? Any clarity on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on which Chromebook you're referring to. CPU cache depends on which processor is used by the device.

For example, the [HP Chromebook 11](http://www.google.com/chrome/devices/hp-chromebook-11/#full-specs-content) has a Exynos 5 Dual (5250) Application Processor. A simple Google search will lead you to the [specifications page of that processor](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/product/application/detail?productId=7668) which tells you that it has 64KB L1 Cache and 1MB L2 Cache.